# A Opensource alternative for basecamp?

Tags: open-source, project-management, basecamp

Is there a Opensource based basecamp alternative?

Or even a free hosted version of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a very good [list of alternatives to BaseCamp online](http://pm-sherpa.com/features/basecamp-alternatives/).

Many are free, other are much less expensive. Check it out to see if any have the capabilities and price-point you are looking for.

For a decent free, hosted service, check out http://www.gomentat.com.

Comment: http://www.gomentat.com seems to be shut down now.

Comment: I have tried many I guess, and searched for many basecamp alternatives, but the closest I was able to find is http://www.timelyprojects.com

Answer (score 2):

I am a Basecamp convert to [ProjectPier](http://www.projectpier.org/), which I have found very comparable, and even better than BC, in some aspects. I've only noticed a couple of very minor bugs, since installing early in the year, but updates may have cleaned those up.

This is a self-hosted solution, which I like.

Comment: ProjectPier seems dead now.
http://www.projectpier.org

Answer (score 1):

There are many [basecamp alternatives](http://www.timedoctor.com/blog/2011/02/02/43-project-management-software-alternatives) which are open source and others have a cost. You can try RedMine or ProjectPier. They are both open source self hosted applications. If you want to try project management software packages with cost, you can try there trial versions and check if you'd like it. Freshbooks, central desktop, deskaway and 5pm are a few of the software packages I've known. I think paid ones do have better functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using ActiveCollab. Older versions are free, newer versions have a cost.

Comment: The older version is here: http://www.activecollab.com/forums/topic/162/

Answer (score 0):

We use [TeamLab](http://www.teamlab.com/) which is open-source, this platform is also offered as SaaS and AMI solution.